# How would I access a different button each time in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have nine buttons created like so:

```py
MyButton1 = Button(game, text="BUTTON1", image=pixel, compound="c", width=200, height=200, command=callback(1))
MyButton1.grid(row=0, column=0)

MyButton2 = Button(game, text="BUTTON2", image=pixel, compound="c", width=200, height=200, command=callback(2))
MyButton2.grid(row=1, column=0)

MyButton3 = Button(game, text="BUTTON3", image=pixel, compound="c", width=200, height=200, command=callback(3))
MyButton3.grid(row=2, column=0)

# and so on
```

I want to change the text of a particular button when it is clicked, and I know that `button.config` can be used to change some things about the button. For example, if I wanted to change the text for `MyButton1`, I could do something like this: `MyButton1.config(text="X")`. But I think it would be quite messy to have a different function for the `command` for each button, so I could create a function like this:

```py
def callback(id):
    print(id)
    # change the text of the button
```

But, my problem is that I don't know how to access the button when the button I am trying to get differs each time. I can't do `"MyButton" + str(id).config`, for obvious reasons (it's a string). So how should I do this?

Comment: Use a list of buttons. You can reference the index in a lambda command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list of buttons. You can reference the index in a lambda command.

By using a list to store our buttons we can reference their index to do whatever we need to. this is very useful when working with widgets dynamically or large amounts of them. This way we can build a simple function to take the index of a list in order to edit what we need. Lambda is good here to set up our commands for each button in a loop.

It is important to note that you cannot simply do `command= update_button(x)` as this will call the function the instance the button is created rather than waiting for you to press it. This is because in the command we called the function instead of saving a reference to it. In order to save a reference to a function we simply omit the the parenthesis like this `command= update_button`.

That said in this situation we really need to pass a variable to it so in order to do this we can write a nameless function called a `lambda` to our command to execute the other command while also passing out variable.

```
import tkinter as tk


def update_button(ndex):
    button_list[ndex].config(text='x')


root = tk.Tk()

button_list = []
for i in range(9):
    button_list.append(tk.Button(root, text='Button {}'.format(i), command=lambda x=i: update_button(x)))
    button_list[-1].pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Results app where a few buttons have been pressed:

[image]

Here is an example using grid with some math to handle grid placement in columns and rows.

```
import tkinter as tk


def update_button(ndex):
    button_list[ndex].config(text='x')


root = tk.Tk()

button_list = []
row = 0
column = 0
for i in range(15):
    button_list.append(tk.Button(root, text='Button {}'.format(i+1), command=lambda x=i: update_button(x)))
    button_list[-1].grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='ew')
    if row % 4 == 0 and row != 0:
        column += 1
        row = 0
    else:
        row += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

If you would rather run columns first then rows simply flip the math:

```
if column % 4 == 0 and column != 0:
    row += 1
    column = 0
else:
    column += 1
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: That seems like a very neat solution, and certainly tidies up the repetitive mess I have so far. Two questions, though: 1) How would I use `.grid` like I did in the question, if the rows and columns are changing, not necessarily based upon their index? It's a 3x3 grid. For example, the first one is `row=0, column=0`, the second is `row=1, column=0`, the fourth one is `row=0, column=1` and so on. And 2) Why do you have to put `x=i` in the lambda, and not just `update_button(i)`?

Comment: @WilliamJones the grid part takes just a little math and tracking I have added an example.

Comment: Ok, I have used your example, and it works perfectly! Thanks for making this excellent solution, which definitely sorted out my code. :)

Comment: @WilliamJones glad to help. Keep in mind a list or a dictionary can be used like this for all widgets. It becomes super useful as your program grows to be able to handle layouts like this dynamically. Or any information really.

Comment: I'll be sure to bear that in mind in the future - thanks for the tip.

Comment: Never thought of doing it like this. Awesome answer.

Comment: @Laif ya its a good way to save on lines of code and a way to manage data/widgets dynamically. Super useful in more complex work. You were half way there with the lambda. Just need to incorporate a list to clean things up a bit. Your answer works fine for less widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Define the button first and then place it inside the callback like so

```
def changetext(button):
  button.config(text="Changed text")

b = Button(master, text="Text here")
b.config(command=lambda button=b: changetext(button))
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. Your code will immediately call `changetext(b)`, and then assign the result to the `command` option.

Comment: I can edit it later, but you could place it inside a lambda

Comment: Just saw your edit, you need to definite button as a variable before the actual lambda function call

Comment: Actually, I think that would probably depend on if the buttons were dynamic. This should be fine, thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm a bit confused. Is it not possible to just add `command=changetext(MyButton1)` to the end of the Button, because it hasn't actually been made yet?

Comment: You couldn’t refer to the button as a variable if it hasn’t been created yet. Therefore you create it first, and then assign the command afterwards